# Undo edit from import?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs

I tried the import from linked in option and it blew away one of my experience sections with all the text in it.  Is there a way to retrieve a previously saved version?

Comment: I fear no such option exists, there are no "revisions" for our profiles. I might be wrong so please be patient and wait for a dev to show up and confirm or hopefully give a better answer. :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I figured there wasn't a way but thought it wouldn't hurt to ask. There should probably be a warning that if a LinkedIn section has the same title as an existing one, that it would overwrite the existing one.

Comment: Hey @user253670, thanks for the report. We decided to add a warning somewhere next to that button, as you suggested. It should be up soon.

Comment: @rla4 6-8 weeks?

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeah, that's probably accurate :D

Comment: Just looking at this now - there is already a warning checkbox "Overwrite my existing description with my LinkedIn description below". If you don't check this, your existing text will be preserved. If you do check this, it will be replaced with the text from LinkedIn. Sounds pretty clear to me! Or am I missing something??

Comment: I am on the screen right now and I don't see any checkbox. On the page that shows my profile, there is a menu on the right with a bunch of links:
- import linkedin
- add github
- add codeplex
... etc.

If I click on import linkedin, I see items from my linked profile with orange buttons saying 'import this one' and a button on top saying 'import all items below'. Nothing indicating that anything will be overwritten (either in a text disclaimer or as a checkbox).

Comment: @user253670 The checkbox only appears if there is a matching existing section, and the text in the section is different from what's coming from LinkedIn.